# convert soap log file to csv using powershell

Tags: linux, powershell, csv, soap, logfile

I have been looking for a good way to convert a log file using powershell into a csv so I can import data correctly into Teradata. I have never seen a file like this before so I am going to try to explain as best as I can.

Here is a sample from the logfile

```html
[XXXXX:11aa11a-123-12a4-12a3-12323aabb123:4] 2021-02-05 00:00:00,000: [DEBUG] Somesystem::Request:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ctx:App xmlns:ctx="http://namespace">
      <ctx:Session>
        <ctx:UN>XXXXX</ctx:UN>
        <ctx:SId>11aa11a-123-12a4-12a3-12323aabb123</ctx:SId>
        <ctx:Creation>2021-02-05T00:00:00+11:00</ctx:Creation>
      </ctx:Session>
      <ctx:IC>
        <ctx:TId>11aa1aa-1aa1-2a22-3aa1-aa1b1233456</ctx:TId>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>13</ctx:BI>
          <ctx:CN>Somesystem</ctx:CN>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BI>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BI>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BI>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BI>
          <ctx:CN>Somesystem</ctx:CN>
          <ctx:CL>UnknownLocation</ctx:CL>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>0</ctx:BI>
        </ctx:Call>
      </ctx:IC>
    </ctx:App>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UT>
        <wsse:UN>SomesystemUSR</wsse:UN>
        <wsse:P>Somepassword</wsse:P>
      </wsse:UT>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns5:ListRequest xmlns:ns5="http://Namespace/Service/V1.0" xmlns="http://www.immi.gov.au/Namespace/Enterprise/ErrorMessages/V1.0" xmlns:ns6="http://Namespace/Core/V1.0" xmlns:ns8="http://Namespace/Service/V1.0" xmlns:ns7="http://Namespace/Core/V1.0" xmlns:ns9="http://Namespace/Core/V1.0"
      xmlns:ns10="http://Namespace/Core/Messaging/V1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://Namespace/Enterprise/V1.0" xmlns:ns4="http://Namespace/Core/V1.0" xmlns:ns3="http://Namespace/WarningMessages/V1.0">
      <ns4:FromDate>2021-01-28</ns4:FromDate>
      <ns4:ToDate>2021-01-28</ns4:ToDate>
      <ns4:Code>0123</ns4:Code>
      <ns4:Type>U</ns4:Type>
      <ns4:Record>S</ns4:Record>
      <ns4:AnotherCode>D</ns4:AnotherCode>
    </ns5:ListRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> (jaxws.LoggingJaxWsHandler) [WContainer : 0] [XXXXX:11aa11a-123-12a4-12a3-12323aabb123BB:4] 2021-02-05 01:00:00,000: [DEBUG] Somesystem::Request:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ctx:App xmlns:ctx="http://namespace">
      <ctx:Session>
        <ctx:UN>XXXXX</ctx:UN>
        <ctx:SId>11aa11a-123-12a4-12a3-12323aabb123BB</ctx:SId>
        <ctx:Creation>2021-02-05T01:00:00+11:00</ctx:Creation>
      </ctx:Session>
      <ctx:IC>
        <ctx:TId>1as23bb3-1er2-234d-234e-bb8b20995147</ctx:TId>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>25</ctx:BI>
          <ctx:CN>Somesystem</ctx:CN>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BranchIndex>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BI>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BI>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BI>
          <ctx:CN>Somesystem</ctx:CN>
          <ctx:CL>UnknownLocation</ctx:CL>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>0</ctx:BI>
        </ctx:Call>
      </ctx:IC>
    </ctx:App>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://xt-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UT>
        <wsse:UN>SomeUSR</wsse:UN>
      </wsse:UT>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <s:ListResponse xmlns:s="http://Namespace/Service/V1.0" xmlns:t="http://Namespace/Core/V1.0" xmlns:m="http://Namespace/Core/Messaging/V1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://Namespace/Service/V1.0 ..\Service\V1.0\Response.xsd">
      <s:List>
        <s:FL>
          <t:lDate>2021-01-05</t:lDate>
          <t:Code>N</t:Code>
          <t:lID>AB123</t:lID>
        </s:FL>
        <s:FL>
          <t:lDate>2021-01-05</t:lDate>
          <t:Code>G</t:Code>
          <t:lID>CD456</t:lID>
        </s:FL>
        <s:FL>
          <t:Date>2021-01-05</t:Date>
          <t:Code>W</t:Code>
          <t:lID>EF654</t:lID>
        </s:FL>
        <s:FL>
          <t:Date>2021-01-05</t:Date>
          <t:Code>P</t:Code>
          <t:lID>TR123</t:lID>
        </s:FL>
        <s:FL>
          <t:lDate>2021-01-05</t:lDate>
          <t:Code>N</t:Code>
          <t:lID>AB123</t:lID>
        </s:FL>
        <s:FL>
          <t:lDate>2021-01-05</t:lDate>
          <t:Code>N</t:Code>
          <t:lID>AB123</t:lID>
        </s:FL>
        <s:FL>
          <t:Date>2021-01-05</t:Date>
          <t:Code>M</t:Code>
          <t:lID>AB345</t:lID>
        </s:FL>
        <s:FL>
          <t:Date>2021-01-05</t:Date>
          <t:Code>C</t:Code>
          <t:lID>AB456</t:lID>
        </s:FL>
      </s:List>
    </s:ListResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> (jaxws.LoggingJaxWsHandler) [WContainer : 3]
```

I want to be able to extract data in a format that is easy to import into Teradata for example

UN, SId, Creation, TId, BI, CN, FromDate, ToDate, Code, Type, Record, AnotherCode, FL, Ldate, Iid,...... so-on

I am open to any suggestions as to having a better way of getting a flat structure of out this soap tree. As you can see the second SoapEnvelope has a lot more data in soapBody than the first one. I am unable to find any question similar to this one.

Note : I do not have access to command line

Comment: You want to have flat structured data but XML is even able to store hierarchical data. So it may be impossible to convert them into a structured form. Or you may loose part of the data when you convert them to a structured form. Did you try to read the data as XML?

Comment: I have not tried reading it as xml yet. The logfiles are named in this form-> name.log.2020-01-01. Is it better to read them as xml first? Would powershell be able to do this?

Comment: Well ... I'm far away from understanding XML really but it looks a lot like XML. Maybe you should follow the link in first node to find out more.

Comment: You might want to modify your log file extraction procedure so that it delivers Json rather than XML.  I think that Json to CSV is easier, based on other questions and answers in here.

Comment: Another path to pursue is whether Teradata can load xml data from soap directly.  Teradata documentation has a section for dealing with XML type data.  One of the things they are likely to support is flattening hierarchical data in the input.

Comment: @WalterMitty I did not think about this, I will definitely have to look into this today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Olaf has stated it might be hard to convert xml into flat csv records.  xml is usually made up of many parent/child object whereas csv is typically single object per row

To help maybe guide your progress you can try taking one of the xml envelopes and converting that to an xml object in powershell by doing the following.

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ctx:App xmlns:ctx="http://namespace">
      <ctx:Session>
        <ctx:UN>XXXXX</ctx:UN>
        <ctx:SId>11aa11a-123-12a4-12a3-12323aabb123</ctx:SId>
        <ctx:Creation>2021-02-05T00:00:00+11:00</ctx:Creation>
      </ctx:Session>
      <ctx:IC>
        <ctx:TId>11aa1aa-1aa1-2a22-3aa1-aa1b1233456</ctx:TId>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>13</ctx:BI>
          <ctx:CN>Somesystem</ctx:CN>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BI>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BI>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BI>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>1</ctx:BI>
          <ctx:CN>Somesystem</ctx:CN>
          <ctx:CL>UnknownLocation</ctx:CL>
        </ctx:Call>
        <ctx:Call>
          <ctx:BI>0</ctx:BI>
        </ctx:Call>
      </ctx:IC>
    </ctx:App>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UT>
        <wsse:UN>SomesystemUSR</wsse:UN>
        <wsse:P>Somepassword</wsse:P>
      </wsse:UT>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns5:ListRequest xmlns:ns5="http://Namespace/Service/V1.0" xmlns="http://www.immi.gov.au/Namespace/Enterprise/ErrorMessages/V1.0" xmlns:ns6="http://Namespace/Core/V1.0" xmlns:ns8="http://Namespace/Service/V1.0" xmlns:ns7="http://Namespace/Core/V1.0" xmlns:ns9="http://Namespace/Core/V1.0"
      xmlns:ns10="http://Namespace/Core/Messaging/V1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://Namespace/Enterprise/V1.0" xmlns:ns4="http://Namespace/Core/V1.0" xmlns:ns3="http://Namespace/WarningMessages/V1.0">
      <ns4:FromDate>2021-01-28</ns4:FromDate>
      <ns4:ToDate>2021-01-28</ns4:ToDate>
      <ns4:Code>0123</ns4:Code>
      <ns4:Type>U</ns4:Type>
      <ns4:Record>S</ns4:Record>
      <ns4:AnotherCode>D</ns4:AnotherCode>
    </ns5:ListRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"@
```

From there you can examine what the object looks like by drilling down into the properties

```
    PS Env:\> $xml

Envelope
--------
Envelope

PS Env:\> $xml.Envelope

soapenv                                   Header Body
-------                                   ------ ----
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ Header Body

PS Env:\> $xml.Envelope.Body

ListRequest
-----------
ListRequest

PS Env:\> $xml.Envelope.Body.ListRequest

ns5         : http://Namespace/Service/V1.0
xmlns       : http://www.immi.gov.au/Namespace/Enterprise/ErrorMessages/V1.0
ns6         : http://Namespace/Core/V1.0
ns8         : http://Namespace/Service/V1.0
ns7         : http://Namespace/Core/V1.0
ns9         : http://Namespace/Core/V1.0
ns10        : http://Namespace/Core/Messaging/V1.0
ns2         : http://Namespace/Enterprise/V1.0
ns4         : http://Namespace/Core/V1.0
ns3         : http://Namespace/WarningMessages/V1.0
FromDate    : 2021-01-28
ToDate      : 2021-01-28
Code        : 0123
Type        : U
Record      : S
AnotherCode : D
```

That's all I got.  I don't know of any way to convert this type of multidimensional object into flat csv other than picking out what you want from the xml object and creating a custom object with those properties.  I'm sure there's someone smarter out there that might be able to offer more :)

UPDATE:
So to take this idea a step further and explain what I meant by creating the custom object I've created this function which will take in the xml object and convert it to a custom object with properties I've picked out of the xml.  After that you can use either the `ConvertTo-Csv` or `Export-Csv` cmdlets to generate the csv/csv file

```
function Convert-SoapXmlToCustomObject
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, Mandatory = $true)]
        [xml[]]$XmlObject
    )

    Process
    {
        if ($XmlObject)
        {
            foreach ($xml in $XmlObject)
            {
                [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                    Sid         = $xml.Envelope.Header.App.Session.SId
                    Creation    = $xml.Envelope.Header.App.Session.Creation
                    Tid         = $xml.Envelope.Header.App.IC.TId
                    Calls       = @() #if each call needs to be separate record maybe use loop to create
                    Username    = $xml.Envelope.Header.Security.ut.UN
                    FromDate    = $xml.Envelope.Body.ListRequest.FromDate
                    ToDate      = $xml.Envelope.Body.ListRequest.ToDate
                    Code        = $xml.Envelope.Body.ListRequest.Code
                    Type        = $xml.Envelope.Body.ListRequest.Type
                    Record      = $xml.Envelope.Body.ListRequest.Record
                    AnotherCode = $xml.Envelope.Body.ListRequest.AnotherCode

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$xml, $xml2 | Convert-SoapXmlToCustomObject | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Output looks like this

```
"Sid","Creation","Tid","Calls","Username","FromDate","ToDate","Code","Type","Record","AnotherCode"
"11aa11a-123-12a4-12a3-12323aabb123","2021-02-05T00:00:00+11:00","11aa1aa-1aa1-2a22-3aa1-aa1b1233456","System.Object[]","SomesystemUSR","2021-01-28","2021-01-28","0123","U","S","D"
"11aa11a-123-12a4-12a3-12323aabb123BB","2021-02-05T01:00:00+11:00","1as23bb3-1er2-234d-234e-bb8b20995147","System.Object[]","SomeUSR",,,,,,
```

Comment: I am going to give this a try and and if it works well, I might try and make it work with Teradata ingestion somehow. I'll update soon. Thanks for the response

Comment: This worked out well. I can manage to get data out of xml and I think I can manage to write this to Teradata with a script in powershell. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for this update, I really appreciate it. I am going to try this out with my data.

Comment: I get this error on running this code Convert-SoapXmlToCustomObject : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'XmlObject' because it is null

Comment: The error message suggest that your xml object is not being created successfully. 
 How are you doing this?  I didn't really cover how to get the xml objects out of the soap log and create the xml objects. General idea is shown at the top of my post where you simply need to take the full xml object and cast it to an `[xml]` object.  I did this just by copy and paste `$xmlObject = [xml]" xml code from your post "`  You will need to find a way to determine the start and stop of these xml objects in the logs and create the xml objects before you can pass them into `Convert-SoapXmlToCustomObject`